# How to get this val(such as gLats in code) out of the function onComplete()?

Tags: javascript

This is the code that I want to work out, it's about AMap.com geolocation API. I want to know how to get this value (such as `gLats` in code) out of the function `onComplete()`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>amap</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cache.amap.com/lbs/static/main1119.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://webapi.amap.com/maps?v=1.3&key=key"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cache.amap.com/lbs/static/addToolbar.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id='container'></div>
 <div id="tip"></div>
 <div id="text"></div>
 <div id="txt"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var map, geolocation;
    map = new AMap.Map("", {
        resizeEnable: true
    });
    map.plugin('AMap.Geolocation', function() {
        geolocation = new AMap.Geolocation({
        });
        map.addControl(geolocation);
        geolocation.getCurrentPosition();
        AMap.event.addListener(geolocation, 'complete', onComplete);
        AMap.event.addListener(geolocation, 'error', onError);      
    });
    function onComplete(data) {
        var str=['succsee'];
        var gLngs=data.position.getLng();
        var gLats=data.position.getLat();
        str.push('longitude：' + data.position.getLng());
        str.push('latitude：' + data.position.getLat());
        document.getElementById('tip').innerHTML = str.join('<br>');
        document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = str.join('<br>');
    }
 function onError(data) {
        document.getElementById('tip').innerHTML = 'failure';
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, you are already accessing the needed values in `onComplete()`:

```
    str.push('longitude：' + data.position.getLng());
    str.push('latitude：' + data.position.getLat());
```

You cannot simply *get* them, `onComplete` is a callback that is called when the values are available. So do anything about them in `onComplete`, you may want to assingn them to global variables, etc, to have them easyly accessible from anywhere in code.

Answer (score 0):

Assigning them to globals is the way to go.

```
    //declare in the global scope 
    var gLats = null;
    var gLngs = null;
    ...

function onComplete(data) 
{
    var str=['success'];
    gLats=data.position.getLat();
    gLngs=data.position.getLng();
    ...
}
```